# Getting rid of the special photo albums on iOS, e.g., People

Tags: ios, itunes, photos, photos.app, album

In the Photos app on my iOS devices, there is the "People" album in addition to the "People From My Mac" album. It seems silly to have both. How can I get rid of the former?

I'd also like to get rid of the "Selfies" and "Panoramas" albums.

FYI: on my Mac on iTunes > iPhone > Photos > Albums, none of "All albums," "Favorites," "Videos," "Last Import," "Selfies," "Panoramas," nor "Screenshots" are checked; only "Albums" and all the albums therein are checked. Additionally, under People, "All people" is checked. Lastly, under "Sync Photos," only "Selected albums" is selected.

On my Mac, I'm running:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.2
- iTunes 12.5.4.42
- Photos 2.0

On my iOS devices, I'm running:

- iOS 10.2